# Turbo-rails distinct scoped partial broadcast update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-rails

I want to broadcast updates of ActiveRecord to distinct partials depending on their scoped route. How could I do that?

Ex: I have a Post model that `has_many :comments`. Comments can be updated and we have two partials for a `comment` in the following folders to display them using a distinct template:

- /views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream_from comment %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment) do %>
  //one way of displaying the comment
<% end %>
```

- /views/**visitor**/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream_from comment %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment) do %>
  //another way of displaying the comment
<% end %>
```

Every time I update the record it is broadcasted using turbo-stream.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 broadcasts_to :post
end
```

The issue is that the broadcasted result is using the `/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` all over the application.
I would want a way to broadcast and re-render the comment using the scoped partial when the view is under a specific scope, and to use the unscoped partial when no scope is defined, is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in the gem...
This can be performed by changing the dom_id of the visitor comment to `"#{dom_id(comment)}_visitor"` and passing the partial explicitly in the broadcast_replace_to

- /views/visitor/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream_from comment %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "#{dom_id(comment)}_visitor" do %>
  //another way of displaying the comment
<% end %>
```

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  after_update_commit do
    broadcast_replace_to self
    broadcast_replace_to self, target: "#{dom_id(self)}_visitor", partial: 'visitor/comments/comment'
  end
end
```